# Auto-create user/drive using delegated permissions and Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I am using the acquireUserCode, acquireTokenWithDeviceCode flow found in adal-node library to authenticate my application and user. This process works successfully and I am then able to make MS Graph calls with the returned token. Where I am stuck is using the /users/{id}/drive endpoint. The docs state:

> If a user's OneDrive is not provisioned but the user has a license to use OneDrive, this request will automatically provision the user's drive, when using delegated authentication.

My understanding is that the device code is a form of delegated permissions but the drive is not being created. Instead I get a 404 response. The user is properly licensed. In testing I have granted all graph delegated permissions to the application registration and "granted" them through the UI. Any pointers where in the chain I should be looking if this scenario is supported? Thanks!

Comment: Just want to point out your understanding is correct. Device code authentication is delegated authentication. Sounds like you are doing everything correctly.